# Store Firebase API Key in Salesforce

Tags: security, namedcredentials

I'm looking for Best Practice how to store API Keys like Firebase in Salesforce.

**Situation**

- For a Salesforce implementation data has to be pushed to Googles Firebase
- The API Key should not be visible for the user, developer or administrator
- We are not building an ISV / AppExchange Application. Therefore, the solution provided here is not applicable: [Securely Storing a static API secret/key in a Salesforce app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/securely-storing-a-static-api-secret-key-in-a-salesforce-app)

**Question**

- What is the best way to store API Keys in Salesforce?
- Can I use Named credentials? There is no type called API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For non ISVs**

After some research I came to the conclusion that there is only a single place where API Tokens should be stored: Named Credentials. I summarized my findings here: [Secure API Keys in Salesforce — Example: Google Firebase](https://www.simple-force.com/best-practice-secure-api-keys-in-salesforce-example-google-firebase/)

In Named Credentials there is no type called "API Key". However, API Keys are pretty much the same as Passwords, therefore it can be stored as a password.

The API Token can be then used in as a merge field in the header of the request.

**ISVs**

Named Credentials are at least visible to the user. Therefore, they are not good choice in an ISV context. There it makes more sense to use encrypted fields.